# с# Нужно сделать так,чтобы оставался след курсора?

Tags: c#

В Windows Forms необходимо,чтобы во время движения курсора за ним оставался след.Как это сделать?

Comment: оставался след где?

Comment: @tym32167, как было на SO на первое апреля в этом году.

Comment: @Qwertiy надо автора того скрипта позвать :)

Comment: @tym32167, https://github.com/tholman/cursor-effects и демки есть.

Comment: А вообще да, оставался где - только над формой или по всему экрану?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point prev = MousePosition;
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            timer.Tick += (o, e) =>
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(prev, MousePosition, Color.Yellow);
                prev = MousePosition;
            };

            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Благодаря [DrawReversibleLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleline?view=netframework-4.8) рисуем не только на своей форме, а гадим по всему экрану.

Если хочется что-то посимпатичней простых линий, можно взять `DrawReversibleFrame`. Так можно и фигурки (звёздочки, например) нарисовать.

Почему цвет линии не тот, что указан? Он реверсивный...

Comment: Я бы клал таймер как компонент на форму. Ну и ещё сомнительно в конструкторе такие вещи делать. Вроде как сама виндовая форма в этот момент ещё не создана? Ну и у таймера интервал не указан, по умолчанию будет 100.

Comment: @Qwertiy - полностью согласен. Код просто как образец, в каком направлении смотреть. И чем плох WinForms - сложно объяснять, как и что сделано в дизайнере. А так сразу видно.